# Erro ao tentar atribuir uma variável no atributo DisplayName no C#

Tags: c#, atributos

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando WinForms no C# que deverá exibir as propriedades das classes para edição em um controle `PropertyGrid`. Estou utilizando a biblioteca `System.ComponentModel` para definir atributos para cada propriedade.
Gostaria de definir para o atributo `DisplayName` um valor que fosse variável, dependendo de como a classe fosse instanciada, mas ao tentar atribuir uma variável, obtenho o erro "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". Abaixo coloco um exemplo do que gostaria de fazer:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace Teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Inixia formulário.
            Application.Run(new Formulario());
        }

        public class Formulario : Form
        {
            TextBox _caixaTexto;
            PropertyGrid _grade;

            public Formulario()
            {
                //Cria rótulo.
                Label rotulo = new Label()
                {
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Location = new Point(20, 20),
                    Text = "Insira um número inteiro",
                };

                //Cria caixa de texto.
                _caixaTexto = new TextBox()
                {
                    Location = new Point(150, 20),
                    Width = 25
                };

                //Cria botao.
                Button botao = new Button()
                {
                    Location = new Point(190, 20),
                    Size = new Size(75, _caixaTexto.Height),
                    Text = "Criar"
                };
                botao.Click += new EventHandler(BotaoClique);

                //Cria grade.
                _grade = new PropertyGrid()
                {
                    Location = new Point(20, 80),
                    Size = new Size(245, 200)
                };

                //Define o formulário.
                this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
                this.ClientSize = new Size(285, 280);
                this.MaximizeBox = false;
                this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { rotulo, _caixaTexto, botao, _grade });
            }

            private void BotaoClique(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int numeroInteiro = Convert.ToInt32(this._caixaTexto.Text);
                ClasseTeste classeTeste = new ClasseTeste(numeroInteiro);
                _grade.SelectedObject = classeTeste;
            }
        }

        public class ClasseTeste
        {
            private string _textoDescricao;

            [Category("Propriedade para teste")]
            [Description("Retorna um número inteiro.")]
            [DisplayName(_textoDescricao)]
            public int NumeroInteiro { get; private set; }

            public ClasseTeste(int numeroInteiro)
            {
                this.NumeroInteiro = numeroInteiro;

                if (numeroInteiro % 2 == 0)
                    _textoDescricao = "Número par";
                else
                    _textoDescricao = "Número ímpar.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: tem que ser uma constante, ou seja, o atributo não pode variar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ser um atributo de uma propriedade, tem que ser uma constante. Isso é da classe e não é alterada dinâmicamente.
Se quer uma descrição de acordo com o estado do objeto, você deve fazer outra propriedade pra isso.

```
public class ClasseTeste
{
    public string TextoDescricao { get=> numeroInteiro % 2 == 0 ? "Par" : "Ímpar"; }

    [Category("Propriedade para teste")]
    [Description("Retorna um número inteiro.")]
    public int NumeroInteiro { get; private set; }

    public ClasseTeste(int numeroInteiro)
    {
        this.NumeroInteiro = numeroInteiro;
    }
}
```

Comment: ueh mais o exemplo não condiz com o que ele perguntou e o seu texto?